# Question about the usage of shared_from_this() in practice

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, enable-shared-from-this

The below code snippet is seen at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

I am curious about what the intention of `Best::getptr()` is? When should I use this method in practice? Maybe a simple demo code helps a lot.

```
struct Best : std::enable_shared_from_this<Best> // note: public inheritance
{
    std::shared_ptr<Best> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    // No public constructor, only a factory function,
    // so there's no way to have getptr return nullptr.
    [[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<Best> create() {
        // Not using std::make_shared<Best> because the c'tor is private.
        return std::shared_ptr<Best>(new Best());
    }
private:
    Best() = default;
};
```

I wrote a simple [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/77PEc4doc) to use `shared_from_this()`, but I still can't see anything meaningful.

If I want to create a new instance, I just call `Foo::Create()`. If I have not called `Foo::Create`, `Foo::getPtr()` is meaningless (i.e. it could not be invoked at all) since there is no valid instance yet.

If I miss something, please let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
 
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
private:     //the user should not construct an instance through the constructor below.                    
    Foo(int num):num_(num) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n"; }

public:
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; } 

    int DoSth(){std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; return 0;}

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> getPtr() { return shared_from_this();}

    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> Create() {
        Foo* foo = new Foo(5);
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo);
    }

private:
    int num_;

};

int main()
{
    auto sp = Foo::Create();
    sp->DoSth();

    Foo& foo = *sp.get();
    auto sp1 = foo.getPtr();
    std::cout << sp.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: when you create an lambda expression, bind a shared_ptr and pass it to others in member function.

Comment: @macomphy Sorry, I can't get your idea. Could you please show me a simple code or a link to make it clear?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/EE3fr3cve

Comment: @macomphy It deserves to be treated as an excellent answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_from_this()` is intended to be used from within the shared class itself (hence its name), not so much by an external entity, which can always have access to a `shared_ptr` to that class.

For example, you can have a class `Database` that hands out `View`s, which have to keep a back-pointer to the `Database`:

```
struct View;

struct Database : enable_shared_from_this<Database>
{
    auto GetView() { return make_unique<View>(shared_from_this()); }
};

struct View
{
    shared_ptr<Database> db;
    View(shared_ptr<Database> db) : db(move(db)) {}
};
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `auto GetView() { return make_unique<View>(shared_from_this()); }`?  `shared_from_this()` invoked in the `Database::GetView()` returns a `std::shared_ptr<std::Database>` ***other than*** `std::shared_ptr<View>`. So it seems wrong to call `make_unique<View>` with parameter whose type is `std::shared_ptr<std::Database>` . How do you think about it?

Comment: Did you miss that the `View` constructor takes a `shared_ptr<Database>`?

Comment: I see. Thank you. After I run the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/9cM18v7PG), I almost fully understand what you say. Is it the ***right way*** to use your demo code?

Comment: By using a private constructor in `Database` and a `Create()` function that returns a `share_ptr<Database>` you ensure that clients will hold the object in a `shared_ptr`; that sounds about right, but is certainly not the only way to handle the situation.